# Haskell: What is wrong with factorial function

Tags: haskell

The following is my factorial function:

```
factorial :: Integer -> Integer
factorial n
  | n < 0 = -1
  | n > 0 = n * factorial (n-1)
  | n == 0 = 1
```

I guess, I covered all the cases (+ve, -ve, 0). When I try to load above code, I am getting following warnings. Why am I getting warnings?

```
Prelude> :load Fact.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Fact.hs, interpreted )

Fact.hs:2:1: Warning:
   Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
In an equation for ‘factorial’: Patterns not matched: _
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
```

Answer (score 4):

This is ghc being conservative. Your code has all possible values of "n" covered, but ghc isn't smart enough to prove that, so it warns you.

Try replacing your "n < 0" with "otherwise" and putting it at the end. This is defined as

```
otherwise = True
```

That will become the catch-all case which will make ghc comfortable.

Comment: That is to say, add a case `| otherwise = error "The impossible happened."` Or something along those lines.

Comment: I think Paul means to handle one of the legitimate cases with a catch-all case. I would [stay away from `error` if possible](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/252977/cleanest-way-to-report-errors-in-haskell).

Answer (score 2):

The compiler can't tell that all inputs match at least one of three guards.

Here's a suggestion to fix that and also remove some repetition:

```
factorial :: Integer -> Integer
factorial n = case compare n 0 of
  LT -> -1
  GT -> n * factorial (n-1)
  EQ -> 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the compiler isn’t smart enough to know that covering the three cases is exhaustive for the particular type. Simply use the `otherwise` pattern in the third rule instead of zero?

(And by the way, factorial is usually only defined for positive integers, so I don’t know how much your negative branch is correct.)